# Given an element A find the previous and next element of A from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
List = ['PK', 'K', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
```

I have another list that has,

```
Grade = ['K','4','8']
```

I would like to see elements previous to 'K' and next to '8' from List and add it to Grade.

Expected result :

```
Grade = ['K','4','8','PK','9']
```

Comment: Why is `PK` at the beginning in the resulting list? Any reason? And can you detail what 'next'  mean? You mean the following element?

Comment: Yes. PK stands for pre-kindergarden.

Comment: I mean does it have to go at the beginning in the resulting `Grade` list? Or can it go at the end?

Comment: It can go in the end as well. Please check the edited result.

Answer (score 2):

this might work:

```
Grade = ['K','4','8']
Grade = Grade + [List[List.index(Grade[0]) - 1], List[List.index(Grade[-1]) + 1]]
# ['K', '4', '8', 'PK', '9']
```

get the index in your `List` and increase or decrease it by 1.

this will raise a `ValueError` if the first and last element of `Grade` are not in `List`.

Comment: This works. Now if my Grade = ['PK','4','8'], the outcome is like, Grade= ['12', 'PK', '4', '8', '9'].  Since PK is the first element in the list,I don't want to have '12' in my Grade to be included. Same applies for the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
lst = ['PK', 'K', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
Grade = ['K','4','8']
Grade = Grade + [lst[lst.index(Grade[0])-1], lst[lst.index(Grade[-1])+1]]
print(Grade) # --> ['K', '4', '8', 'PK', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

`Grade.insert(Grade.index('8'), l[l.index('8')+1])`

or this way for the previous item

`Grade.insert(Grade.index('K'), l[l.index('K')-1])`

it's best not to call your list "List", since that's an existing class in python

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ['PK', 'K', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
Grade = ['K','4','8']
List[:List.index(Grade[0])]+ Grade + list(List[List.index(Grade[-1])+1])
#['PK', 'K', '4', '8', '9']
```

Comment: This works. Now if my Grade = ['PK','4','8'], the outcome is like, Grade= ['12', 'PK', '4', '8', '9'].  Since PK is the first element in the list,I don't want to have '12' in my Grade to be included. Same applies for the last element.

Comment: @JenniferTherese the outcome would be `['PK', '4', '8', '9']` when `Grade = ['PK','4','8']`